# FOSUserBundle: Get EntityManager instance overriding Form Handler

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am starting with Symfony2 and I am trying to override FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler of FOSUserBundle.

My code is:

```
<?php

namespace Testing\CoreBundle\Form\Handler;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler as BaseHandler;
use Testing\CoreBundle\Entity\User as UserDetails;

class RegistrationFormHandler extends BaseHandler
{

    protected function onSuccess(UserInterface $user, $confirmation)
    {
        // I need an instance of Entity Manager but I don't know where get it!
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        // or something like: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager

        $userDetails = new UserDetails;
        $em->persist($userDetails);

        $user->setId($userDetails->getId());

        parent::onSuccess($user, $confirmation);
    }
}
```

So, the point is that I need an instance of Doctrine's Entity Manager but I don't know where/how get it in this case!

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not use `EntityManager` directly in most of the cases. Use a proper manager/provider service instead.

   In case of FOSUserBundle service implementing [`UserManagerInterface`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManagerInterface.php) is such a manager. It is accessible through `fos_user.user_manager` key in the service container (which is an allias to [`fos_user.user_manager.default`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/orm.xml#L8)). Of course registration form handler [uses that service](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/registration.xml#L26), it is accessible through [`userManager`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler.php#L33) property.
2. You should not treat your domain-model (i.a. Doctrine's entities) as if it was exact representation of the database-model. This means, that you should assign objects to other objects (not their ids).

   Doctrine is capable of handling nested objects within your entities (`UserDetails` and `User` objects have a direct relationship). Eventually you will have to [configure cascade options](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) for `User` entity.
3. Finally, `UserDetails` seems to be a mandatory dependency for each `User`. Therefore you should override `UserManagerInterface::createUser()` not the form handler - you are not dealing with user's details there anyway.

   1. Create your own `UserManagerInterface` implementation:

      ```
      class MyUserManager extends \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager {
          /**
           * {@inheritdoc}
           */
          public function createUser() {
              $user = parent::createUser();

              $user->setUserDetails(new UserDetails());
              // some optional code required for a proper
              // initialization of User/UserDetails object
              // that might require access to other objects
              // not available inside the entity

              return $user;
          }
      }
      ```
   2. Register your own manager as a serive inside DIC:

      ```
      <service id="my_project.user_manager" class="\MyProject\UserManager" parent="fos_user.user_manager.default" />
      ```
   3. Configure FOSUserBundle to use your own implementation:

      ```
       # /app/config/config.yml
       fos_user:
           ...
           service:
               user_manager: my_project.user_manager
      ```

Comment: Many thanks for all the information, that is a full answer! Tomorrow I will be working with these tips and I will give you my feedback.