# Modifying User entity when registering using FOS User Bundle and Symfony2

Tags: events, symfony, service, fosuserbundle

As many people know, the FOS User Bundle doesn't provide roles automatically when a user registers. The most common solution is to either a) modify the User entity constructor to automatically assign a role, or b) override the entire registration controller.

Neither of these solutions seems perfect, and I want to make use of the Events that the FOS user bundle provides.

I have managed to capture the event I want (`FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE`), but I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the modified User entity back to the registration form.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
namespace HCLabs\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

class AutoRoleAssignmentListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return [ FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'onRegistrationInitialise' ];
  }

  public function onRegistrationInitialise( UserEvent $event )
  {
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $user->addRole( 'ROLE_USER' );

    // what do
  }
}
```

The YML for the event listener:

```
services:
    hc_labs_user.reg_init:
        class: HCLabs\UserBundle\EventListener\AutoRoleAssignmentListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

If more code is needed I'm happy to provide it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FOSUserBundle: Get EntityManager instance overriding Form Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574665/fosuserbundle-get-entitymanager-instance-overriding-form-handler)

Comment: @byf-ferdy not a duplicate, that question is in regards to overriding a controller. Mine was about hooking into the event instead.

Comment: but as far as I can see the solution could have been the same.

Comment: @byf-ferdy if I wanted to create unnecessary code and ignore new functionality that is specifically designed to make the above fix obsolete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is very simple - you have to do **nothing** to get updated `User` object in registration form after updated `User` in event listener for `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE` event.

Let me explain. `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE` is dispatched in `RegistrationController` by:

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, new UserEvent($user, $request));
```

And, before this dispatch in code (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L43) new `User` is created:

```
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, new UserEvent($user, $request));
```

During dispatching, by default PHP `call_user_func` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php ) is called with pasted event name (function in defined object) and `Event` object. After that, event listener has possibility to modify pasted `Event` object - particularly event property.

In your case, your event listener modify `User` property via:

```
$user = $event->getUser();
$user->addRole( 'ROLE_USER' );
```

So in fact, you have to do nothing to pass the modified User entity back to the registration form.

Comment: But the modified user still isn't being sent back. I put in some code to dump the `$user` after the event is dispatched, and the `roles` key is still empty.

Comment: `ROLE_USER` is default Symfony2 registered user role. Please try add another role like `ROLE_USER_X`.

Comment: that worked! Funnily enough, I was just about to try something similar, since `$user->setName( 'Jack' );` worked. Do you know why I can't use a Symfony2 role? Doesn't make much sense to me. But thanks, to both of you, I will mark this as answered now.

Comment: The default UserGroup 'ROLE_USER' is stored as an empty array. That might caused some confusion. If you use 'ROLE_USER' it is in fact stored correctly (as an empty array).